# Sum of Predicted Values

Tags: r

I am using a loan table to perform logistic regression. I am trying to find the optimal threshold for maximum profit. How can I take the sum of the profits for all loans that are predicted to be good in the new_status column. So if the threshold value is 0.5, we would sum the profit for all loans with predicted probability > 0.5.

[image: Loans Data]

Answer (score 1):

subset the `profit` values where `new_status = 'Good'`. If your dataframe is called `df` :

```
sum(df$profit[df$new_status == 'Good'], na.rm = TRUE)
```